# Need 2D Rotation interpolation logic

Tags: math, matrix, rotation, interpolation, angle

[See this Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcwX.png)

I need logic for rotation interpolation

```
 public static float interPolateKeyForAngle(int startFrame, int endFrame, int currentFrame, float initialAngle, float endAngle)
{
    int frameDif = endFrame - startFrame + 1;
    int difCurrentFrame = Math.abs(startFrame - currentFrame) + 1;

    //Calculate here
}
```

I know starting angle in 0th position and end angle in 10th position i need to calculate the 1 to 9th position angles some one please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: something like this: `return ((endAngle - initialAngle)*(currentFrame - startFrame))/(endFrame - startFrame) + initialAngle;`

Comment: i already try this calculation its only rotate the clock wise i need to calculate shortest path and find the angle in that direction.

Comment: Which could mean that you need to normalize the angle difference to be between -Pi and Pi. Try using `delta = endAngle - initialAngle; delta = fmod(delta + 3*Pi, 2*Pi) - Pi`.

Comment: Image added....

Comment: It should be 0 instead of 180 in the picture. -- Your critical case seems to be when, for instance, going from 20 to 290 degrees you do not want to go the positive 270 degrees, but the reverse 270-360=-90 degrees.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is this Java? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete linear interpolation between two values is always

```
(V0.(n-i) + V1.i) / n
```

where `0≤i≤n`, for `n` intervals (i.e. `n-1` intermediate values).

Comment: The problem is that angles wrap around 360° degrees, and so this algo is going fail sometimes. The direction of interpolation should be specified also I think.

Comment: @ja72: you should have mentioned that in the question. Add to `V1` a suitable multiple of `360°` so that `V1-V0` is the total rotation angle, in the right direction. Note that it is impossible to find that multiple from the given `V0` and `V1` alone.